# Magento is Linking to Bad 404's Somewhere

Tags: magento, bad-request

I am trying to fix 404 pages through Webmaster tools however Magento seems to be linking to bad 404 pages somewhere. I don't believe users will be able to access these however spiders seem to be and I need to stop this somehow.

Here is an example of the link:

http://www.kidsrooms.co.uk/catalog/product/view/id/400/s/deluxe-pirate-ship-and-accessories/category/444/%s

Any responses will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you migrated the site from some other platform ??

Comment: Yes I have, sorry for the slow response.

Answer (score 0):

first truncate `core_url_rewrite` table manually from sql side, then reindex from admin panel.

All old and unwanted URl will updated.